# Construct a function such that its adherent values are the compact set $K$

Tags: real-analysis

I really need help, this question seems really crazy, I don't know even how to begin, please any help is welcome.

QUESTION

> Given a real number $a$ and a non-empty compact set $K\subset \mathbb
> R$, construct a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the
>   adherent values of $f$ in the point $a$ be $K$.

EDIT

**Definition of adherent values of $f$ in the point $a$**

> A real number $c$ is called adherent value of $f$ in the point $a$
>   when there is a sequence of points $x_n\in X−\{a\}$ such that $\lim
>  x_n=a$ and $\lim f(x_n)=c$

thanks a lot

Comment: What does "adherent point of $f$ in the point $a$" mean?

Comment: My suspicion is that the constant function $f(x)=a$ would work.

Comment: @user42912: Where is the question from?

Comment: I think this is saying that the closure of $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)=a\}$ is $K$

Comment: In the case what I said is correct, consider the function $d(x,K)=\inf\{|y-x|:y\in K\}$ and see if that would help you construct the function you want.

Comment: @JonasMeyer a real number $c$ is called adherent value of $f$ in the point $a$ when there is a sequence of points $x_n \in X-\{a\}$ such that $\lim x_n=a$ and $\lim f(x_n)=c$

Comment: @user45150 sorry, there is a typo, I wanna say adherent value, I'm going to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ denote the quotient of the abelian group $\mathbb R$ with addition by its subgroup $\mathbb Q$.  Let $K$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$, and let $\varphi:(\mathbb R/\mathbb Q)\to K$ be a surjection.  Define $f(x)=\varphi(x+\mathbb Q)$.  This example works because every coset of $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, so for all $y\in K$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)\to a$ such that $x_n\neq a$ and $f(x_n)=y$ for all $n$.  Assuming $K$ is closed, there are no other adherent values, because the range of $f$ is $K$.

Comment: where can I use the fact that $K$ is compact? thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @user42912: Just as you were commenting I was adding the remark that closedness of $K$ implies that there are no other adherent values.  Beyond this compactness isn't used in this example.

Comment: then we don't need the fact that $K$ is bounded?

Comment: It is not used in this example.  Perhaps for more constructive examples it would useful.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "range of f"?

Comment: @user42912: The range, or image, of a function $f:A\to B$, denoted $f(A)$, is the set $\{y\in B:\exists x\in A, f(x)=y\}$.  In this case $f(\mathbb R)=K$.  An adherent value is a limit of a sequence in the range of the function, and since $K$ is closed, all adherent values must remain in $K$.

Comment: How can we guarantee that there is such surjection?

Comment: [Disclaimer: I am assuming the axiom of choice wherever needed here.]  The elements of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ form a partition of $\mathbb R$, and each element is countable.  This implies that the cardinality of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ is equal to that of $\mathbb R$.  Hence there are surjections from $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ to any subset of $\mathbb R$.